# given a number and its root value, finding nth root of a number

Tags: c++, c

can someone please explain this below-mentioned code?

```
double b=0.0;
double a=0.001;
double r=0;
printf("Type the number and root value \n");
scanf("%lf %lf",&b,&r);
while(pow(a,r)<(b + 0.05)){
a += 0.001;
}
printf("The %f root of %f is = %f\n",r,b,a);
return 0;
```

for example, if the number is 32 and the root value is 5

output: the 5 root of 32 is = 2

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: I also suggest you learn about [*rubber duck debugging*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: It's just a silly trial and error with an incrementing solution, and not very accurate. It's nonsense when a negative number is entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a simple trial and error method where you take a random small number as a base and increment it to a power(which is r in your case) until it becomes greater than or equal to your desired number.

Here, your random number is a, which you increment every time until pow becomes greater than b.